# Default argument of type float = gibberish

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-c++

I have some trouble using a default argument of type float:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void fun(T t = 1e-05);

template<typename T> inline
void fun(T t)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    fun<float>();

    _getwch();
    return 0;
}
```

It prints -1.36867e-033 instead of the equivalence of 1e-05. What is going on here?

I'm using VC++10.

**EDIT1:**

Thank you all for your replies.
But casting the default argument doesn't work in the following case:

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T t = static_cast<T>(1e-05));

template<typename T> inline
void fun(T t)
{
    std::wcout << t << std::endl;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    fun<double>();
    fun<float>();

    _getwch();
    return 0;
}
```

So this is definitely a bug and worth reporting?

**EDIT2:**

[Reported this issue to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/677851/faulty-convertion-of-default-parameters-of-floating-point-types-for-templates)

Comment: You are expecting the compiler to emit a conversion from double to float.  It doesn't.  Using "1e-5f" fixes it.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report this.

Comment: Maybe you need `wcout` on your platform?

Comment: @Hans: Subtle. I was about to suggest `fun(T t = T(1e-05))` but thought that that wouldn't be necessary... It works fine on GCC 4.6 by the way.

Comment: @Kerrek: How is `wcout` relevant here? Why would you expect that to solve the problem?

Comment: It works in the IAR compiler as well.

Comment: @Cody: No, you're right, never mind -- I was just worried about mixing two different-width outputs...

Comment: Hmm, this workaround trips the compiler: `template <typename T> struct def_arg { static const T value; };
template <typename T> const T default_arg<T>::value = T(1e-05);

template<typename T> void fun(T t = default_arg<T>::value);

template<typename T> inline
void fun(T t)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}`

Comment: @MSalters: Thanks. But to me, it's a little too much work for something so simple. I've already reported this issue to Microsoft. I think I'll just wait for the fix. It'll probably come with VS2012.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks to be an issue with a default template argument and conversion between double and float. The issue doesn't occur if you aren't using templates.

Stick an "f" at the end of that default template argument such that it treats the value as a "float" instead of a double.  That seems to fix it.

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T t = 1e-05f);
```

But after applying the above fix, if you declare this

```
fun<double>()
```

you get an equivalent bug.  So a better fix that works for both floats and doubles is to use a cast as follows:

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T t = (T)(1e-05));
```

As to whether this is a compiler bug or "undefined behavior", I'll let the compiler gurus chime in.

Comment: Not a bad answer, and it adds a little extra to the earlier comments, but still -1 for not even acknowledging the insight from Hans and Kerrek....

Comment: @Tony: That answer is wholly my own.  While I was writing up my answer and validating the solution, I wasn't able to see the comments.  S.O .will notify you of other submitted answers while you are writing your own.  But you can't see new comments until after you post.  And yes, I hate it when people steal my answers and get the credit.  But this is an honest mistake.

Comment: well, the mistake's mine then... I'd "-1 to +1" but can't unless your answer's edited.  And apologies...!  Cheers.

Comment: The issue doesn't occur either if you remove the separate declaration and move the argument to the definition.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, I noticed that too.